# How can I make a macro to copy an entire column but change a single row number?

Tags: excel, vba

I have inherited a poorly designed workbook, and I am trying to make it work a bit better without starting from scratch.
The last problem I have is that I have a formula in a column that I need to copy to the next column, but change the row number referenced in the formula. The easiest thing to do would be to change the format of the workbook but that will cause an uprising by the users.

```
=IF((CommaSeparatedListContains(RTM!$I$8,ROW()-2))=TRUE,"X","")
```

The code above is what I need to copy, but I need to change it so that it looks at I9 instead of I8. RTM is the name of the sheet that the cell is on, and CommaSeparatedListContains is a macro that will return true if the referenced cell has a value (ROW()-2) in the comma delimited list.
Basically I need a macro to add a new column to the worksheet that works like the others, so that the end users who don't know how to use Excel can just click a button and add a column.
For example, that code is in cell A1, and I need to move it to B1 keeping the I the same but increment the row number. If I remove Both $ signs it would change it to J8, if I have $I8 it stays I8, and if I have $I$8 it stays I8.

Comment: $I$8 to $I8, and if you just copy it, the reference will be dynamic and become I9.

Comment: @Cyril - that will work if you copy it *down the row* - but user needs across the column.

Comment: @Scott Holtzman is correct. Copying it across the column it just stays I8.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman, Doh... i took the wrong fixed section off.  "$" is used to fix the item, so if you want the COLUMN dynamic, you will use I$8 (given the example).  If you want BOTH to be dynamic, you have I8; currently, they are both fixed, $I$8.

Comment: @Cyril - user needs *row to move down 1* when formula is *copied 1 column over*

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I guess I'm not understanding that from the question.  Maybe an image might help?  What I think I'm reading is that there is a macro which has a fixed reference to row 8 in column 9, aka column "I", to determine if the activecell should have an X or not.  If their is a column added in the active region, the fixed reference needs to be row 9 in column 10.  If this is the case, then the fixed reference cell can be somethign such as Cells(i,i+1), where i is a column count or sorts (hell, use find to search for the header and make i the column that is in, making is Cells(i-1,i)).

Comment: @Cyril I'm not sure how I can explain it different. What I need is a simple way to take the exact formula I have above, and paste it into a new column. Let's say that right now that formula is in column A. I want column B to be looking at cell I9 instead of I8. So each column I move the formula over needs to look at the next row down on the RTM sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for re-affirming my understanding.  I'll give this a shot with providing some code, based on your string:

```
Dim LC as Long, i as Integer

Columns(9).Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Cells(1,10).Value="" 'Add your header

LC = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
i = LC-1 'See description below code

Range("J2:J100").Formula="=IF((CommaSeparatedListContains(RTM!$I$" & i & ",ROW()-2))=TRUE,""X"","""")"
```

For i, you want to ensure that you substract the correct number... given the example of I8 being the cell you want to reference, and assuming that Column I is the last column of your sheet, then the 9th column, 8th row, is the cell you want to reference.  So, the variable i = last column - 1, in this example.

In this case, the column is always added to the right of column I, the assumed last column in the sheet.

One other assumption is that you're using rows 2 to 100 for the range that you have the formula... So, Range("J2:J100").Formula will be affected by your actual range for the formula.